# Join tables based on condition in Hive

Tags: sql, join, hive, conditional-statements

I have two tables and have mentioned the layout of tables in the below screenshot.

[image]

Using `Id` column I need to join two tables. Whenever there is a match with `Id` (example `Id` is `a2`), I need to take the corresponding values from `Table2`. In some scenario, `Id` from `Table1` will not be there in `Table2` (example `Id` is `a1`). In that case, I have to take values from `Table2` where the value of `Id` in `Table2` is `all`.

For better clarification, I have mentioned the **Expected output** in the below screenshot.

[image]

I tried the below code, but don't seem to be working.

```
select distinct t1.Id,t1.Name,t2.Phone1,t2.Phone2    
from Table1 t1  
left join Table1 t2 on t1.Id = case when t2.Id is null then t1.Id else t2.Id end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `left join`s, where the second brings in the default values:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.phone1, t2d.phone1) as phone1, coalesce(t2.phone2, t2d.phone2) as phone2
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id left join
     table2 t2d
     on t2d.id = 'All' and t2.id is null;
```